# Play a loaded file in javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, audio, filelist

I'm trying to load a file from the user and want to play it with javascript.

The file is loaded correctly, and I can access it seeing the name, the type and so on, with the  `FileList` API.

What I can't do is to play the obtained file. I tried to do

```
myFile.play();
```

like I always do with loaded file, but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to play the media content, instead of using FileReader, i suggest you to use the createObjectURL method. It is more efficient since it do not create a string containing the file content.

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL

Just do :

```
audio/video.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(myFile);
```

Don"t forget to revoke your uri when loading another media file to avoid memory leaks :

```
window.URL.revokeObjectURL(audio/video.src);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `FileReader` API too ([API compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/File#Browser_compatibility)) and your browser need support HTML5 `audio` tag.

Something like this:

```
   <body>
       <input type='file' id='fileInput' />
       <audio id='player' />
       <script type='javascript'>
           var fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
           var freader = new FileReader();

           freader.onload = function(e) { 
               document.getElementById('player').src = e.target.result; 
               document.getElementById('player').play(); 
           }

           fileInput.onchange = function(e) {
               var files = e.target.files;
               freader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
           }

       </script>
   </body>
```

You can read [here](http://www.michael-gerhaeuser.de/?f=fileapi/readme.html) for more.

My answer based on [migerh's](http://www.michael-gerhaeuser.de/) solution